# Making an array with random values

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am trying to fill an array with random int values from 0 to 6. To control my code i am printing out the random values I generate. I try to exclude duplicates in the nested if-statement inside the for-loop, but when I run the code I get my seven values, but some of them are still duplicated. Can someone please help me?
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class TesterArrayer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int size = 7;
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int randomArray[] = new int[size];

        for(int x =0; x < size; x++)
        {                                               
            int randomValue = randomNumber.nextInt(6);
            if (randomValue != randomArray[x])
            {
                randomArray[x] = randomValue;
            }

        }//End for-loop

        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            System.out.println(randomArray[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For starter you have size defined as 7 so you will see 7 elements. as per duplicate you can use Sets as the will discard duplicates. SEE THIS QUESTION FOR MORE CLARITY http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345771/pick-a-few-random-numbers-in-a-specific-range-without-duplicates

Comment: Execute your algorithm manually, on paper, by noting the value of each variable at each iteration. And look at the javadoc of `Collections.shuffle()`.

Comment: Note that `randomNumber.nextInt(6)` returns a random number from 0 to 5, not 0 to 6.  (I'm assuming you want both 0 and 6 to be possible values in the array.  Otherwise, you can't generate a 7-element array without at least one duplicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 7;
        boolean add = true;
        int counter = 0;
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int randomArray[] = new int[size];
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            randomArray[j] = -1;
        }
        while (counter < size) {
            add = true;
            int randomValue = randomNumber.nextInt(7);
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                if (randomValue == randomArray[x]) {
                    add = false;
                }
            }// End for-loop
            if(add)
            {
                randomArray[counter] = randomValue;
                counter++;
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            System.out.println(randomArray[y]);
        }
    }
```

Try something like this.  You don't want to add the number unless it's not already in the list.  Also for your random you need 7 instead of 6 if you want 0-6.

This code will fill your array with 0-6 not repeating any numbers.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem! One more question: Does the if(add) statement equal if(add == true)?

Comment: Your welcome I'm glad I could help!  1. Yes except if(add == true) 2 equal signs. 2. So they aren't initialized to 0 because if you just declare an int[] then all of the elements will initially be set to 0.  You wan't 0 to be one of your random numbers so I assign -1 because it is not in your set 0-6.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the numbers 0..length-1 in random order you can do something like this:

```
    int length = 7;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(length);
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        list.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    //list is now in order, need to randomly shuffle it
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    //now list is shuffled, convert to array        

    int array[] = new int[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        array[i] = list.get(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **minLimit**, **maxLimit** and **noOfItems** to get random Numbers

```html
public class RandomIntegers
{
    public static final Random random = new Random();
    public static final int maxLimit = 6;
    public static final int minLimit = 0;
    public static final int noOfItems = 7;
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Set<Integer> uniqueRandomIntegerSet = new HashSet< Integer >(); 
        
        while(uniqueRandomIntegerSet.size() < noOfItems)
            uniqueRandomIntegerSet.add( random.nextInt( maxLimit - minLimit + 1 ) + minLimit );  
        
        Integer[] randomUniqueIntegers = uniqueRandomIntegerSet.toArray( new Integer[0] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you should use a more optimal data structure for this approach, as mentioned in the other answer and comments, you can still accomplish this with an array of course. As you have defined the problem you would need to change `int randomValue = randomNumber.nextInt(6);` to `int randomValue = randomNumber.nextInt(7);` or else this will loop infinitely as there is no possible way to have no duplicates in a size 7 array with only 6 values.

You can do something like this to modify your code for it to work:

```
boolean flag = false;

for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)
{                                               
    int randomValue = randomNumber.nextInt(7);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {            
        if (randomValue == randomArray[i])
        {
            //randomArray[x] = randomValue;
            flag = true;
            x--;
        }
    }
    if (!flag)
        randomArray[x] = randomValue;

    flag = false;

}//End for-loop
```

This code is simply flagging when it sees a duplicate value in the array already and will skip this value and `decrement` the `x` value so that it will create another random value for this spot in the array.

Answer (score -2):

```
byte[] source = new byte[1024];

Random rand = new Random();
rand.nextBytes(source);
```